# Decode pictures from database

Tags: python, database, image, hex

In a database I have there's a column called `photo` which has characters in it that begin like this:

```
0xFFD8FFE000104A46494600010101012C012C0000FFDB00430008060607060508070707...
```

How can I make an image from this data?

(The complete data can be viewed and downloaded from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwY7chTWtykwQlJweFdtMDAwM3M/view?usp=sharing).)

Comment: Please post a small, simple example of your problem without linking externally!

Comment: What database and what is the data type of the photo column

Comment: MsSql -> Image field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something along these lines (the 'pict.txt' file contains hex data downloaded from the link in your question):

```
import io
from PIL import Image

with open('pict.txt', 'rb') as img_file:
    img_file.read(2)  # skip over the '0x'
    hex_data = img_file.read()
    binary_data = hex_data.decode('hex')
    memory_file = io.BytesIO(binary_data)
    img = Image.open(memory_file)
    img.show()
```

Running it displays the following image:

[image: image from data linked to in question]

After opening the image memory file and creating an instance of the `PIL` `Image` class, you can access other image attributes such as `img.format`, `img.mode`, `img.size`, etc as needed (see [Image Class Attributes](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/reference/Image.html#attributes)).